# Execute program as normal user (while being root)

Tags: linux, bash, debian, root

I'm working on Debian 8 (Jessie) (64 bits). I want to run program as normal user, without creating and switching accounts to normal user.

I am running the main program from bash script:

```
screen ./run
```

where run contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -c unlimited
while true; do ./tfs --log-file "output.txt" "error.txt" | tee out.txt; done
```

I want to run the 'tfs' as normal user

Comment: `su` command is for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
su - -c "screen /path/to/run" username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -u username
```

is the command you are looking for.